# How to pass values to DataAccess Layer for storing into database in asp.net MVC5 API?

Tags: api, asp.net-mvc-5, data-access-layer

In my API application, I field values coming from registration view which I want to store into the database. On AccountController.cs, I have collected these values using the following code.

```
[Route("Register")]
    public async Task<object> Register(UserDetails data)
    {
        var userRegister = new IdentityUser
        {
            FirstName = data.FirstName,
            LastName = data.LastName,
            UserName = data.Email,
            Email = data.Email,
            PhoneNumber = data.PhoneNumber,
            PasswordHash = data.Password
        };


        UserManager<IdentityUser> _manager = new UserManager<IdentityUser>(new UserStore<IdentityUser>(new TachusApi.DBContext.AuthDbContext()));
        string pHash = _manager.PasswordHasher.HashPassword(data.Password);

        DBAccess dbaccess = new DBAccess();

        dbaccess.SaveAdmin(userRegister, pHash);

        return data;
    }
```

What I want to do is to pass these values to the SaveAdmin method in DBAccess.cs for storing into the database. Here is my SaveAdmin method:

```
#region Save Admin User

    public void SaveAdmin(string userRegister, string hash)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = null;
        SqlCommand command = null;
        int retValue;

        conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        conn.Open();

        command = conn.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = "RequestedServiceUserDataInsert";
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;


        ...

    }

    #endregion
```

I can't pass a valid format of the values to my SaveAdmin method where I can save them into the database. Is there anyone who may advise an effective way that can help me pass these values as an object for using them in my save method? Please advice

Comment: Since you're using ADO.NET how do you pass the parameters to the stored procedure?

Comment: @JaggenSWE I am actually getting issues with passing values to the SaveAdmin method. Once I am done with it, I'll make do with stored procedures

Answer (score 0):

Since you define the userRegister object as an IdentityUser object

```
    var userRegister = new IdentityUser
    {
        FirstName = data.FirstName,
        LastName = data.LastName,
        UserName = data.Email,
        Email = data.Email,
        PhoneNumber = data.PhoneNumber,
        PasswordHash = data.Password
    };
```

And then pass it to the `SaveAdmin` function of your dbaccess class

```
    dbaccess.SaveAdmin(userRegister, pHash);
```

The SaveAdmin method needs to be set up to accept the userRegister of type IdentityUser. Right now it expects a plain string.

So, instead of having your `SaveAdmin` function declared as this:

```
public void SaveAdmin(string userRegister, string hash)
```

You need to have it declared like this:

```
public void SaveAdmin(IdentityUser userRegister, string hash)
```

That way the method gets the data it expects and you can access all properties of that object and insert them into SQL server.

Comment: like you stated above, I have already tried to declare SaveAdmin method like this but it gives me *The type or namespace 'IdentityUser' could not be found.* error.

Comment: Yeah, does it exist in the same namespace otherwise you need to include either the complete path in the SaveAdmin void declaration for that variable OR have a `using`statement where you import that namespace so it can find the object definition. Check if there's any `using` statement to the models or similar in the AccountController.cs and copy that to the DBAccess class as well. Or (at least in Visual Studio 2017), put the marker on the userRegister in the void declaration and hit Ctrl + .

Comment: That is Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework namespace but VS do not allow me to use it in both cases. i.e during the declaration of SaveAdmin method and importing it as using statement.